# Num_steps of LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, lstm

Could you tell me why the num_steps is set to 1 in a evaluation?
"https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L305"

I think that the eval_config.num_steps is set to be same number with config.num_steps.

Answer (score 0):

The that language model is for predicting the next word given **a word** based on the neural network which has been trained using sentences/more precisely sequences(that's why the config.num_steps are much much larger than 1).  The [default number](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L254) is 2, that is to say, given the previous two words to predict the upcoming one word.

Hope I'm right and this helps.

Comment: This is wrong. The model predicts word by word both in training and in testing. Both, for training and testing it uses the hidden state of the previous timestep, thus possibly using information from multiple timesteps before. The default number for num_steps is not 2 as the default configuration is "small" (see top of file where they define the flag default values) which has num_steps of 20.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out. I'll check and update soon.